# eMail via SMS gateway is sent, but not received

Tags: c#, sms

I am trying to send a free SMS from a gmail account to an airtel mobile (in Karnataka) using a C# Windows application.  The message is sent and I can see sent items, but it is not received by the mobile phone.

This is my code,

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youraccount@gmail.com", "activedust");          
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.To.Add("919845no@airtelkk.com");//replace  no with airtel mobile number in Karnataka

message.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@gmail.com", "App",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
message.Body = "type your body";
message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
smtp.send(message);
```

I can send emaill successfully using this code but for sms not working

Comment: Try sending the email somewhere else, to check if it is actually received as en email instead of an SMS

Comment: Email to SMS gateways are notoriously bad at reliably delivering messages. You could very well be being blocked by the carrier or marked as spam.

Comment: You don't need any account for using [smtp](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipédia:Oracle/semaine_43_2013#Envoyer_un_SMS_par_e-mail "Just look the session example; you don't need to understand French for it").

Comment: Is this question still valid? After more than a year and half has passed?

Comment: @smileever143 check if the number is DND activated or not.Numbers with DND activated will not get SMS from special numbers.Also there are some other limitations.Let me know if you are trying to send DND numbers or not

Comment: check For DND services for that number

Answer (score 2):

You have to activate this service on mentioned mobile number. If it is not activated then you will not receive SMS on mobile it require 49/- charges or something like that.

If not activate you can activate and give try again

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to send a text message with your gmail account

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public void SendTextMessage(string subject, string message, long telephoneNumer)
        {
            // login details for gmail acct.
            const string sender = "me@gmail.com";
            const string password = "mypassword4gmailacct";

            // find the carriers sms gateway for the recipent. txt.att.net is for AT&T customers.
            string carrierGateway = "txt.att.net";

            // this is the recipents number @ carrierGateway that gmail use to deliver message.
            string recipent = string.Concat(new object[]{
            telephoneNumer,
            '@',
            carrierGateway
            });

            // form the text message and send
            using (MailMessage textMessage = new MailMessage(sender, recipent, subject, message))
            {
                using (SmtpClient textMessageClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    textMessageClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    textMessageClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    textMessageClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sender, password);
                    textMessageClient.Send(textMessage);
                }
            }
        }
```

For a List of Sms Gateways check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Note: When the recipent responds to the message the message will be sent to your gmail account...Great for backups Smile | :)
And read [How to send SMS to mobile using SMTP server in windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635594/how-to-send-sms-to-mobile-using-smtp-server-in-windows-application)