# How to send SMS to mobile using SMTP server in windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp, sms

I am developing a windows application using C#, in which i want to send SMS to some user based on some condition. i goes through the many forum post to "Send SMS using SMTP Server" but none of them use-full for me. In **[this](http://joelbennett.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/sending-text-messages-via-sms-to-a-mobile-phone-from-a-c-windows-application-via-gmail/)** i got some clue to send SMS through Gmail SMTP but not working as i think it is carrier specific (not sure).
My code sample :

```
try
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add("1568235685@sms.sancharnet.in");
    message.From = new MailAddress("sameone@gmail.com"); //See the note afterwards...
    message.Body = "Hi, How r you ?";

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someonet@gmail.com", "password");

    smtp.Send(message);
    MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
```

above code not giving any exception or error but also i am not getting any sms on my number as well.

**So, what i want to ask that is there any way to send SMS using SMTP server to the mobile number of any carrier?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to send to the SMS gateway. It is provider specific.

Wikipedia has a [List of SMS Gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways).

For example, to send to a Sprint PCS number you would send to number@messaging.sprintpcs.com, where number is the phone number (i.e. 5551234567, or whatever).

Comment: @Bhushan: "but not working" doesn't give us much to go on. Did you get an error? Have you checked the provider's Web site to see if you need to do something special? Some of those gateways require other information.

Comment: It does not giving any error but also i am not getting the sms on my mobile, i also checked the provider website http://www.bsnl.co.in/opencms/bsnl/BSNL/services/broadband/sms.html . I think it need some credential for using it's sms gateway.

Answer (score -1):

For those who have looked so much for a free way to send SMS from a web app, and are in France, and having FreeMobile as operator, I've just found a way in calling a free web service provided by FreeMobile. I've written this code in C# and it works fine.

```
private void SendSMSAlert(String message)
{
    try
    {
        String url = "https://smsapi.free-mobile.fr/sendmsg?user="YourFreeMobileIdentifierHere"&pass="YOURPASSHERE"&msg=" + message;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch(WebException e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("SMS Not Sent! Exception "+e.ToString());
    }

}
```

So if you have a freeMobile line in France, you can get your Pass from https://mobile.free.fr/moncompte/

Then, if you need to forward the SMS to other numbers, it can be done with many mobile apps on AppStore or GooglePlay.

I hope this helps!