# How to send sms using asp.net C# (For Free)

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

How can you send sms using either asp.net or WinForms C#.
I have read about Gateways/API which you need to pay for.
Is there a way I can do this for free?

Comment: Perhaps this is useful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19635594/56778

Comment: Look into using email gateways. If you email `yournumber@vtext.com`, that will send a text to the specified number for a verizon customer. You'd have to maintain support for different carriers though, but that's the cost of doing it free :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [Twilio's API](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) specifically their [Send a message](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) function.

**Not free**, but certainly not expensive either.  $1 / month and then 3/4 of a cent each message.  Its pretty standard issue these days for doing what you want to do.

I just today came across another API with a free trial plan that would work for a demo or prototype app.  https://www.nexmo.com/pricing/ which is very similar in features to Twilio.

Comment: I'll delete my answer as someone decided to downvote it, was basically the same but suggested textmagic :) http://api.textmagic.com